# How to bypass authentication while solr startup

Tags: java, solr

I am using solr 8.1.1 version. I've implemented jwt authentication script in security.json file.

below is my security.json script with authentication and authorization

```
{"authentication":{
"blockUnknown":false,
"class":"solr.JWTAuthPlugin",
"jwk":{
  "kty":"oct",
  "use":"sig",
  "kid":"k1",
  "k":"10A02618BE6943C22FD81CA49F6FCF063B6E1732C3614BC3ACA6032B6B3215CAF0D28A34FD423423CA3AC34BEA27D3F79",
  "alg":"HS256"},
"aud":"solr",
"adminUiScope":"solr"},"authorization":{
"class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
"permissions":[
  {
    "name":"read",
    "path":"/select/*",
    "role":"solr-update",
    "index":1},
  {
    "name":"all-admin",
    "collection":null,
    "path":"/*",
    "role":"solr-update",
    "index":2},
  {
    "name":"update",
    "role":"solr-update",
    "index":3},
  {
    "path":"/*",
    "role":"solr-update",
    "index":4}],
"user-role":{"solr":"solr-update"},
"":{"v":0}},"auditlogging":{
"class":"solr.SolrLogAuditLoggerPlugin",
"async":false}}
```

With the above script, authentication is working fine with the below jwt token generated from jwt.io

eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzb2xyMSIsImF1ZCI6InNvbHIiLCJleHAiOjk5MTYyMzkwMjJ9.o9mIkcLwXQPHLX4IyE2L1yW6tPlTIDUzEBh4bjHW0oSzlSkGf1ch8ibOVipMrnuZ5uR6uEm3D_IxXcFWhFcFfw

while starting solr, there are few API's which executes with authentication. So, i want to bypass/disable them (admin/info, admin/cores) because of that, I'm not able to access solr dashboard.

Is there any way to disable admin API's while loading solr instance.

[solr dashboard screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd25e.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for - how do you define "while loading", since you're talking about the dashboard?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the quick response. Sorry for the miscommunication, actually i was not able access solr admin UI after enabling JWT authentication in security.json file.

So, after spending few hours on the internet, I've figured out the issue, actually, while enabling solr JWT authentication, Solr dashboard is sending unknown request to solr server without authentication. I need to enable authentication on solr admin UI side as well to access all admin API's that requires authentication for solr admin UI.

Comment: Hi @LakhanGupta I have same question . How you have resolved. Could you please share steps . We are using solar 8.9.